# How can I get string from onTimeResponse via SNTPClient?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use SNTPClient: https://github.com/aslamanver/sntp-client-android

and this Toast is giving true rawDate result.

```
SNTPClient.getDate(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo"), new SNTPClient.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeResponse(String rawDate, Date date, Exception ex) {
    
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rawDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

But, this Toast is giving null result.

```
Private String strdate;
...

SNTPClient.getDate(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo"), new SNTPClient.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeResponse(String rawDate, Date date, Exception ex) {
    
    strdate = rawDate;

    }
});

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strdate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

How can I get string from onTimeResponse via SNTPClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Solved) My solution: I can getting and using string via this solution.

```
Private String strdate;
...

public void getstrdate(String rdate) {

    strdate = rdate;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strdate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

SNTPClient.getDate(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo"), new SNTPClient.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeResponse(String rawDate, Date date, Exception ex) {
    
         getstrdate(rawDate);

    }
});
```